# Spark and HBase version compatibility

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

I am trying to integrate Spark and Hbase 1.2.4. I am currently using hadoop 2.7.3. Can somebody tell me which version of Spark is compatible with HBase 1.2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using spark version 1.6 with hbase version 1.2 . So I think spark version 1.6 or 1.6.x will definitely work with hbase 1.2.4.

Comment: I was trying to configure Spark 1.6.3 but getting an error: ERROR [main] spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/10.0.0.1 to master:8021 failed on connection exception. And I am using hduser@master:~$HBASE_PATH=`/usr/local/hbase/hbase-1.2.4/bin/hbase classpath` . hduser@master:~$./spark-shell --driver-class-path $HBASE_PATH to connect hbase from spark shell. Is that a right procedure to connect with hbase or I have to do something else. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Siddhartha, what version of hadoop you are using?

Comment: Hadoop version 2.7.2

Comment: Thanks Siddhartha, Spark 1.6.3 and HBase 1.2.0 working together.

Comment: Spark 2.1.0 and HBase 1.2.4 also working without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check below link for detailed compatibility table

http://hbase.apache.org/hbase-spark/dependencies.html

Comment: Thanks for the info.